# How to keep data frame data types when exporting to Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have `pandas` data frame with `int64` , `object` , and `datetime64[ns]` data types. How to preserve those data types when exporting `pandas` `DataFrame.to_Excel` option?

I want exported Excel file columns looks like this:

`int64` Number format in Excel

`object` Text format in Excel

`datetime64[ns]` Date format in Excel

Right now all of my Excel column format shows as **General**

Answer (score 1):

> I have pandas data frame with int64 , object , and datetime64[ns] data types. How to preserve those data types when exporting pandas DataFrame.to_Excel option?

The short answer is that you can't.

Excel does't have as many datatypes as Python and far fewer than Pandas. For example the only numeric type it has is a IEEE 754 64bit double. Therefore you won't be able be able to store a `int64` without losing information (unless the integer values are <= ~15 digits). Dates and times are are also stored in the same double format and only with millisecond resolution. So you won't be able to store `datetime64[ns]`.

You could store them in string format but you won't be able to use them for calculations and Excel will complain about "Numbers stored as strings".

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Pandas dataframe to an Excel file with column formats using Pandas and XlsxWriter.

Here is an example of what you can do: [Pandas Excel output with column formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html)

For more possibilities, have a look at this page, especially the `Format methods and Format properties` section: [The Format Class](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)